# Change The Font Size of The Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I want to change to a bigger font size in the `PowerShell` **Package Manager Console** in Visual Studio.

How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The font size can be changed by adjusting the settings for "Package Manager Console" within the "Fonts and Colors" section of the options popup (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Font and Colors).

Comment: see answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397619/in-visual-studio-how-to-change-package-manager-font-size