# How to Change The Package Manager Console Font Size?

Tags: visual-studio

I cannot find the screen and what option that would change the font size specifically for Package Manager. How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you change the font of package manager console only.

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options**
2. Select **Font and Colors** under the **Environment**.
3. From the drop down menu of **Show Settings for:** select **Package Manager Console**
4. Change the properties according to your liking.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]